# Simulate incoming call on own android device

Tags: android, phone-call, spoof

I want to fake an incoming call on my own (physical!!! -> not the emulator) android device. I know there are lots of apps that actually can do that, which means it cant be that hard - I just need a hint. Searching the net only brings up apps which do the job.

Comment: "I know there are lots of apps that actually can do that" -- name any.

Comment: "Fake Call & SMS", "Fake-A-Call" for example

Comment: I don't think those apps actually do what you would like to achieve. They don't actually trigger a call they just display something that looks a bit like an incoming call.